# How many ways are there to put 6 identical balls to 3 distinct bins such that no bin is empty?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to put 6 identical balls to 3 distinct bins such that no bin is empty ?

---

I tried to solve by stars and bars problem. As it is saying that no bin is empty, means every bin must have atleast one ball.

After, putting one ball in each I am left with three balls. So left 3 balls can be put in C(5,2).

But, the answer is 540. Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: This is equivalent to solve $a_1+a_2+a_3=6$ with $a_i \geq 1$. Can you now apply the stars and bars technique?

Comment: I have applied the same. But, answer is 540

Comment: The answer is for the wrong question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The count of distinct ways to distribute 6 *identical* balls among 3 distinct bins is indeed: $$\binom{3+2}{2} = 10$$

The count of distinct ways to distribute 6 *distinct* balls among 3 distinct bins is: $$3^6- \binom{3}{1}2^6+\binom 3 2 1^6 = 540$$

Comment: Thanks Graham for clearing .

Answer (score 2):

The stated problem is equivalent to finding the triples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ with $a_i \geq 1$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3=6$. By the stars and bars [technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one), this number is $\binom{5}{2}=10$.

The answer is indeed 10.

Comment: I have applied the same. But, answer is 540 .

Comment: I don't see why... But maybe you and me are missing something here.

Comment: The question said *identical* but the answer given was for *distinct*.